# Cantor function and uniform convergence

Tags: real-analysis, sequence-of-function

I was reading about [Cantor function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor_function#Alternative_definitions) but I don't really understand the reasonning from wikipedia.

If we have

$\max_\limits{x \in [0, 1]} |f_{n+1}(x) - f_n(x)| \le \frac 1 2 \, \max\limits_{x \in [0, 1]} |f_{n}(x) - f_{n-1}(x)|, \quad n \ge 1$

Then we have

$\max\limits_{x \in [0, 1]} |f_{n+1}(x) - f_n(x)| \le \frac {1} {2^{n+1}} \max\limits_{x \in [0, 1]} |f_{1}(x) - f_0(x)|$

So $\forall x, f_n(x)$ is a cauchy sequence and since $\mathbb{R}$ is complete, we have that $f_n(x)->f(x)$ pointwise. But am missing the argument that allows us to say that

$\max\limits_{x\in[0,1]}|f_n(x)-f(x)|\le\frac{1}{2^{n+1}}\max\limits_{x\in[0,1]}|f_1(x)-f_0(x)|$

Comment: It's not $<$. It's $\leqslant$.

Comment: What about proving that by a little induction ?

Comment: Oh, yes, I see. $\max\limits_{x\in [0,1]}\lvert f_{n+1}(x)-f(x)\rvert \le \max\limits_{x\in [0,1]}\lvert f_{n+1}(x)-f_n(x)\rvert+\max\limits_{x\in [0,1]}\lvert f_{n}(x)-f(x)\rvert$ and then I can use induction and the result above. Thanks!